# RxJava Observable.interval can be delayed on Android?

Tags: android, performance, rx-java, rx-java2

I am developing an Android app.
It should do some work every 1 minute. (60 seconds)

To do this, I used "RxJava - Observable.interval".

```
Observable.interval(0L, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe { 
            // do something
        }
```

But actually, it doesn't work very exactly like...

```
2020-03-12 11:27:21.771
2020-03-12 11:28:21.787
```

There is a delay of about 0.016sec.
But it's ok, it is reasonable...

What I want to know is that...
If the performance of the device is lower and lower... 
Can a delay of more than 1 or 2 seconds occur?

```
2020-03-12 11:27:21.771
2020-03-12 11:28:22.787   // <-- 1.016sec delay, is it possible?
```

If it can occur... how can I fix it?
Could changing the scheduler be the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The scheduling of events in the Java environment is subject to delays; you will almost never get a a spot on delay to occur. The issue is that the clock resolution of the underlying operating system is probably no better than 10 milliseconds. Here, you are seeing a jitter of about 16 milliseconds, which is not surprising. **This is not only a problem with RxJava.**

If you read the documentation for your platform where it discusses sleeps, timers, etc, you will see that there are several notes and warnings. Usually the documentation will say that it will sleep for *at least* the given time.

In general, you have to determine how much drift you can support in your application. Then test over a sufficient interval (one sample isn't reasonable, but 10,000 may be).

You can find out more at [Understanding RxJava Timer, Delay, and Interval Operators](https://blog.mindorks.com/understanding-rxjava-timer-delay-and-interval-operators)